# BitmapFactory.decodeStream from Assets returns null on Android 7

Tags: android, bitmapfactory, android-assets, android-7.0-nougat

How to decode bitmaps from Asset directory in Android 7?

My App is running well on Android versions up to Marshmallow. With Android 7 it fails to load images from the Asset directory.

My Code:

```
private Bitmap getImage(String imagename) {
    // Log.dd(logger, "AsyncImageLoader: " + ORDNER_IMAGES + imagename);

    AssetManager asset = context.getAssets();
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = asset.open(ORDNER_IMAGES + imagename);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Log.de(logger, "image konnte nicht gelesen werden: " + ORDNER_IMAGES + imagename);
        return null;
    }


    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, PW, PH);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    // Lesen des Bitmaps in der optimierten Groesse
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);

}
```

As a result (only Android 7) `BitmapFactory.decodeStream` is null. It works correctly an older Android APIs.

In debug mode I see the following Message:

> 09-04 10:10:50.384 6274-6610/myapp D/skia: --- SkAndroidCodec::NewFromStream returned null

Can someone tell me the reason and how to correct the coding?

Edit: Meanwhile i found, that removing of the first BitmapFactory.decodeStream with inJustDecodeBounds=true leads to a successful BitmapFactory.decodeStream afterwards with inJustDecodeBounds=false. Don't know the reason and don't know how to substitute the measurement of bitmap size.

Comment: My guess is that your problem is particular to your asset. I just tested [one of my book samples](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Bitmaps/InSampleSize) that loads images from assets, on a Nexus 9 running Android 7.0. It seems to work fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think we are in the same boat. My team stuck in this problem for a while like you.

It seems be a problem in BitmapFactory.cpp (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/jni/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.cpp) Some code was added in Android 7.0 and made the problem occurred.

```
// Create the codec.
NinePatchPeeker peeker;
std::unique_ptr<SkAndroidCodec> codec(SkAndroidCodec::NewFromStream(streamDeleter.release(), &peeker));
if (!codec.get()) {
    return nullObjectReturn("SkAndroidCodec::NewFromStream returned null");
}
```

And I found out the `BitmapFactory.decodeStream` method didn't create the bitmap after we set `inJustDecodeBounds=false` but when I try to create bitmap without bound decoding. It's works! The problem is about BitmapOptions in that InputStream doesn't updated when we called `BitmapFactory.decodeStream` again.

So I reset that InputStream before decode again

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromAssets(Context context, String fileName, int width, int height) {
    AssetManager asset = context.getAssets();
    InputStream is;
    try {
        is = asset.open(fileName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
    try {
        is.reset();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, width, height);
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

It's looks like we have to reset InputStream every time before reuse it.

Comment: This did the trick. Just resetting the InputStream. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I tried this trick, but I keep getting "mark/reset not supported" IOException when calling rest. But I use FileInputStream, cause I try to load bitmap from SD card.

Comment: Is there any other way but FileInputStream to open file from storage?

Comment: Thanks, it helped me. Android 7, file was used from resources (png image). Adding `inputStream.reset()` is safe to use in previous versions so add it if you're re-using the same inputstream.

Comment: Android 7.1.2 and it's not working. 
To make it work i have to change reset() for close() and than create new stream before next decodeStream()

Comment: Had the same problem with Android 5.1, Thanks to you it solved +1.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the android default security config is not letting you download a file using protocol "http://" (no encryption).

Try finding an image or file with an "https://" protocol.  See if that causes your file to load.  Otherwise, set a Network Security Config that allows "http".

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone, I was bumping up against a similar issue updating older code that had previously worked for resizing images. **My issue was further up the stack where I was reading data from the image file.** I made use of `IOUtils.toByteArray(Reader)`, which has been deprecated. I switched to converting to a byte array directly from the URI and now it is working well. See the first two lines of `resizeImage()` below for the example of that new method (The rest of the code allows me to resize the image.)

```
public static Bitmap resizeImage(Uri imageUri, int targetWidth, int targetHeight) {
    // Convert the image to a byte array
    java.net.URI tempUri = new URI(uri.toString());
    byte[] imageData = IOUtils.toByteArray(tempUri);

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.length, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, targetWidth, targetHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    Bitmap reducedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.length, options);
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(reducedBitmap, targetWidth, targetHeight, false);

    return resizedBitmap;
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a 
        // power of 2 and keeps both height and width larger
        // than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```