# BitmapFactory.decodeStream returns null when reading from internal storage

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I attempt to read images from the internal storage,
when I decode `FileInputStream, BufferedInputStream` or a `File`
using `BitmapFactory` I get `null` as a result:

```
//mImages is an ArrayList of image file names, "a.jpg","b.jpg", etc.
//This is inside my custom adapter for returing ImageViews from mImages:

public View getView(int position, View ..., ViewGroup...){
Context base_context = MyApplication.getAppContext();

String currentImageFilename = mImages.get(position); //say this is "cat.jpg"

//after this line f = "/data/user/0/mobile.foo.bar/files/cat.jpg"
File f = base_context.getFileStreamPath(currentImageFilename);

Boolean ex = f.exists(); //returns true, inserted only for debugging as no 
//exception was thrown when decoding the bitmap and the result is null

BufferedInputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));

Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buffer); // img is null after this line
imageView.setImageBitmap(img);
}
```

I tried all other answers I could find, but no luck so far.

Comment: Try with smaller images. You took such big ones.

Comment: Please tell the value of full path. You hide what you are doing with all those functions. Your f.exist() should be used in such a way that you display a toast if f does not exists and then return. Now f.exists() has no iinfluence on flow.

Comment: Thanks @greenapps the .exists() is was only inserted, so that I can confirm to myself that the files are found as I debug, I didn't intend to keep it. The full path is now above in the edited version, the images are only 18kb each.

Comment: Remove the BufferedInputStream.

Comment: Still not working, not with decodeFile or decodeStream either. Yet, the file exists. What goes wrong is totally invisible, because when debugging as I go deeper step-by-step I get down to the native system API decoder and I can't see further...

Answer (score 5):

If you're running this code on **Android 7** and you use `BitmapFactory.decodeStream` you need to reset `InputStream` every time you want yo use it again.
For example I used it twice, first to get some metrics and then to decode into Bitmap. And it worked fine on all versions prior to Android 7.

Now I need to reset it, otherwise it returns `null`:

```
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iStream, null, options);
...
try {
    iStream.reset();
} catch (IOException e) {
    return null;
}
...
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iStream, null, options);
```

Resetting inputStream won't cause any bugs on older versions so it's safe to use.

If it helped in your case - all credits to this guy:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/41753686/5502121

Comment: Thank you, it wasn't necessary in my case, I instead made a custom directory for the images upon saving and then used `this.getDir("MyImagesFolder", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getAbsolutePath() + File.Separator + "myimage.jpg";` to read them and it worked. I appreaciate your help and it may help someone else who lands here.

Comment: For Android >= 10 for me I had to re-call openInputStream each time before calling decodeStream when trying to use 2 different options